# Recording Touches on UIView

Tags: objective-c, graphics, touch

I've got an app where I can draw onto some 'slides' to make notes. What I want to be able to do is 'save' these notes so they can be viewed at another time. Perhaps creating a file with touch tracking information, which can then be 'loaded' at the users convenience.

I have the code for drawing on the screen as follows:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

So how do I modify this code to allow touch tracking and thus saving to a file?

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this. You can either save the image. See docs on `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` and `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` The other way is to save the touch locations.

ie.

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:[NSValue valueForCGPoint:currentPoint]];

You can then save this array out with `[array writeToFile:<valid file path> atomically:YES]`. Finally to get the lines back reread the file and recreate the paths.

Comment: I'm trying to decide which one to go for. There's the text file which will be low in memory but harder to code and then theres the image. Which would you do if you were in my situation?

Comment: It depends, if you want the user to be able to continue drawing where they left off. The array. If its saved for good save the image out.